# which version should I install for intel atom CPU 230 @ 1.6 GHZ, 1G Ram acer aspire revo?

Tags: software-recommendation

I have an Acer Aspire Revo R3600 , intel atom CPU 230 @ 1.6 GHZ, 1G Ram, 120G hard disk and currently running window xp (but in the system properties, it says 895 ram only).  it is slow and so I would like to install ubuntu os on it to improve the performance but not sure what version of ubuntu I should install.  I only found previous literature that people installed Ubuntu version 9.x in this machine written in 2009.  now that ubuntu has higher version.  Can someone advise what is the ubuntu version I should install given this machine spec? anyone tried it?

also, does this version support other lanugage (chinese)?

Answer (score 1):

You can install either [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/)32bit, or [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/)32bit.  Both have low system requirements, and will run good on your machine.

Lubuntu is a fast and lightweight operating system developed by a community of Free and Open Source enthusiasts. The core of the system is based on Linux and Ubuntu . Lubuntu uses the minimal desktop LXDE, and a selection of light applications.<sup>Lubuntu</sup>

Xubuntu is an elegant and easy-to-use operating system. Xubuntu comes with Xfce, which is a stable, light and configurable desktop environment.

Xubuntu is perfect for those who want the most out of their desktops, laptops and netbooks with a modern look and enough features for efficient, daily usage. It works well on older hardware too.<sup>Xubuntu</sup>